# MySql Query - Insert into A select * from B (while B still populated)

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I'm using mysql 5.5,
What happen when I'm execute query like:

```
Insert into A select * from B ;
```

And at the same time other process inserting records to table B?
Does InnoDB can handle this situation? the tables will be synchronized at the end of the exectcution?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from Mysql documentation of [Locks Set by Different SQL Statements in InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locks-set.html)

> **INSERT INTO T SELECT ... FROM S WHERE** ... sets an exclusive index
>   record without a gap lock on each row inserted into T. If
>   innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog is enabled and the transaction
>   isolation level is not SERIALIZABLE, InnoDB does the search on S as a
>   consistent read (no locks). Otherwise, InnoDB sets shared next-key
>   locks on rows from S. InnoDB has to set locks in the latter case: In
>   roll-forward recovery from a backup, every SQL statement must be
>   executed in exactly the same way it was done originally.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Even if they were in sync after the `INSERT`, new inserts would quickly make them out of sync.

What is your *real* goal?